# Want the button hide for 2 hours even after refresh/reload the page & it's for the specific registered user

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, dynamic

After timer countdown reach 0 button will appeared & when registered user click on the button, it should disappeared or hide for that specific user. Even on page reload or refresh button shouldn't appeared before 2 hours counted from the click event time.

When registered user click on the claim button it should hide & countdown timer should be counting continuously with loop system.

```js
var clicks = 0;
    var interval = -1;
    function showTimer(selector, seconds) 
    {
        var startTime = Date.now();
        
        function showRemaining() 
        {
            var delta = Date.now() - startTime;     // milliseconds
            var deltaSeconds = delta / (1000);
            if (deltaSeconds < seconds) {
                // display minutes remaining
                $(selector).text(Math.round(seconds - deltaSeconds));
            } else {
                $(selector).text(0);
                clearInterval(interval);
                $("#proceed").show(); // Look at here
            }
        }
        if( interval > -1 ) clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
        showRemaining(); 
    }
    $(function() {
        showTimer("#countdown", 10);
    });
    //when click button
    function onClick() {
        $("#proceed").hide();
        alert("Successfully Added Your Points Into Your Wallet");
        $("#clicks").text(++clicks);
        showTimer("#countdown", 10);
    };
```

```css
.container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 30%;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 20px;
      background: coral;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #countdown {
      font-family: montserrat;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: bolder;
      color: #fff;  
    }
    #proceed {
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 20px;
      padding: 15px;
      background: transparent;
    }
    #btn {
      font-family: montserrat;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bolder;
      color: #fff;  
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <span id="countdown"></span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button type="button" id="proceed" onclick="onClick()"><a href="#" id="btn" class="btn btn-1">Claim Your Points</a></button><br>  
    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you want to save user specific data that persists on reload and/or browser closing, use localStorage or cookies. If you need it to be permanent and not changeable by the user, you will need to use a database

Comment: My question is-
When I reload page, countdown reset but I want the countdown continue.
I want to hide the button for 2 hours, after 2 hours it will again appeared for that specific user. I don't want it permanently hidden. I want it 2 hours basis when registered user click on the button.

Please help me some to modify my code.

Comment: Yes, you need to use cookies or localStorage for that. On reload or if you close your browser, all your code executes from the beginning again, dynamic value will not be stored anywhere unless you tell the browser to do so.
Thankfully, it should be easy to find information on that matter. I advise reading documentations and tutorials on that matter.
Here is a helpful link for cookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp, and here for localstorage: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

You might need to set cookie expiration date too

Comment: I did tried to reach but again I failed. It's not working on page refresh or reload. When I reload the page button set activated. But I don't want that.

The Key Point Is - Timer finish & reach 0, button show/activated/clickable. When click the button it should disable/hide for 2 hours even after reload or refresh the page.
https://codepen.io/solaimanhakkani/pen/bGYKBXZ

Comment: As I said - your timer resets when you reload or refresh. This is normal and expected behaviour. You need to store your countdown value (the timestamp) in a cookie or localstorage and read it before you execute any code.

Picture this - your user clicks the button. 10 minutes pass, user closes the browser window. Next time user opens the browser window, your code executes exactly how you told it to - it executes everything completely like the first time, the countdown value is lost because it's not saved anywhere.